# Excel index formula to inspect a row in reverse order

Tags: excel, indexing, row

I am new to Excel formulas. I am using this formula:

```
=INDEX(B$1:G$1,MATCH(H2,B2:G2,0))
```

It appends the corresponding column name, when values in a range of rows `(B2:G2)`, match my target `H2`.
The problem with this is that when two equal values are found, the leftmost is appended, whereas I'd rather have the rightmost appended.

I would like to have the same thing, but performed the other way around (matching done from `G2:B2`).
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=MAX(IF($B$2:$G$2=H2,COLUMN($B$2:$G$2)-COLUMN(INDEX($B$2:$G$2,1,1))+1))
```

Put it and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> together.